# Ruby Method - Won't Take Second Parameter - Blackjack

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters

Building a blackjack game. If I put a second parameter in the display_cards method, everything breaks down. If I take out the parameter from the method and then call it, everything works fine. What's going wrong?

```
def play
  game_deck = initialize_deck
  game_deck = shuffle_deck(game_deck)
  human_cards = []
  computer_cards = []
end

def initialize_deck (number_of_decks = 6)
  deck_values = ["A", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
  suits = ["-Hearts", "-Diamonds", "-Clubs", "-Spades"]
  deck = []
  number_of_decks.times do 
    suits.each do |suit|
      deck_values.each do |value|
        deck << value+suit
      end
    end
  end
  return deck
end

def display_cards (player_cards , player_name)
  card_string = "#{player_name}'s Cards\n-----------------"

  player_cards.each do |card|
    card_string += "\n| #{card}"
    card_string += "\n-----------------"
  end
  puts card_string
end

def shuffle_deck(deck , number_of_shuffles = 6)
  number_of_shuffles.times do
    deck = deck.sample(deck.count)
  end
  return deck
end

def pull_card(game_deck, player_cards)
  player_cards << deck.shift
end
test_cards = ["A-Hearts", "3-Spades", "10-Diamonds"]
name = "ARealHumanBean"
display_cards (test_cards , name)
```

Comment: `deck` is an array. Array has a shuffle! method. Shuffling 6 times is not useful.

Comment: Thanks steen. Simplified the code :) And thanks for the solution guys. Glad my logic was okay. But sheesh. Lot of headbanging over an extra space!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the space, Ruby beleive "(test_cards , name)" is the first argument and complains about the missing second argument.

These syntax will work

```
display_cards(test_cards, name)
display_cards test_cards, name
```

Answer (score 1):

remove the space here:

```
display_cards (test_cards , name)
             ^
```

Ruby is I think treating (test_cards, name) as a block or a struct and trying to pass it to your function display_cards as a single argument.

Interestingly enough it works perfectly in jruby.

Comment: Certainly not a block, which requires block start/end tokens.